# Place to learn about the classification of real-analytic structures

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

I'm at the end of my master in math and until now I've mostly done analysis. My knowledge is on differential geometry is basic (on the level of Lee's book). What would I need to learn to get an understanding of the classification of real-analytic structures on low-dimensional (up to 3) manifolds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Analytic_manifold) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moise%27s_theorem). Then you may want to read Moise's book.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds really promising. I'll check it out tomorrow.